# Set defalult plot linewidth in .octaverc

Tags: plot, octave

I am starting out with Octave. I am using Octave 4.2.0 (compiled from source) on Debian.

I have found that using the qt or fltk graphics_toolkit, have default linewidth of 0.5. I want to change the default linewidth in my .octaverc file.

I have tried adding the following to my .octaverc (separately) but they both cause errors

```
linewidth:def.1.5000
set(gca (), "defaultlinewidth", "1.5")
```

How can I change the default line width of plots via the octaverc file?

Comment: What errors do they cause?

Comment: 1. "linewidth:def.1.500", error:                                                          "parse error near line 9 of file /home/meow/.octaverc
syntax error
>> linewidth:def.1.5000
                  ^                                                                                                         error: source: error sourcing file '/home/meow/.octaverc'
error: execution exception in /home/meow/.octaverc"                                    2. 'set(gca(), "defaultlinewidth", "1.5")' error: invalid line property 'width'
error: execution exception in /home/meow/.octaverc' and shows fig

Comment: Remove the double quotes around "1.5" and there is two times line: `defaultlinelinewidth`. Just added this comment because I ran into the quote problem and it's not explicitly mentioned in the (otherwise perfect) answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want to set it on the root so that all plots will use it:

```
set(0, "defaultlinelinewidth", 1.5);
```

[Here is the link](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Managing-Default-Properties.html) to the relevant part of the manual.

> 15.3.5 Managing Default Properties
>
> Object properties have two classes of default values, factory defaults
>   (the initial values) and user-defined defaults, which may override the
>   factory defaults.
>
> Although default values may be set for any object, they are set in
>   parent objects and apply to child objects, of the specified object
>   type. For example, setting the default color property of line objects
>   to "green", for the root object, will result in all line objects
>   inheriting the color "green" as the default value.
>
> set (0, "defaultlinecolor", "green");
>
> sets the default line color for all objects. The rule for constructing
>   the property name to set a default value is
>
> default + object-type + property-name
>
> This rule can lead to some strange looking names, for example
>   defaultlinelinewidth" specifies the default linewidth property for
>   line objects.

**EDIT:**

Just to place emphasis on this: You've tried to set "defaultlinewidth" which is **not** a valid property as explained above. The property you want to set is "defaultlinelinewidth"

Comment: thanks but I still get the following error `error: invalid line property 'width'
error: execution exception in /home/meow/.octaverc`

Comment: @XeroSmith: Please be sure to execute or add the line exactly as in my answer. Your last comment looks like you've tried to set "defaultlinewidth" which is invalid as explained above